# Initialization of member variable via parentheses doesn't work

Tags: c++

For the following codes, can anyone explain why we can't initialize the variable `data` by parentheses?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class X
{
private:
    int data(1); // wrong here

public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << data << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    X temp;
    temp.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isnt actually much to explain, its just not valid syntax. Default member initializers are

```
class X
{
private:
    int data{1};     // ok
    int data2 = 42; // also ok

public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << data << endl;
    }
};
```

While `int data(1);` is not valid syntax for a default member initializer. See here for details: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members

Comment: but why does this work int main()
{
    int data(1);
    return 0;
}

Comment: @HelloWorld because thats not a default member initializer

Comment: @HelloWorld The rules are [given here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem.general). For class members, the syntax is `declarator brace-or-equal-initializer(opt)`. Parentheses are not listed as allowed for class members. In `int main() { int data(1); return 0;}`, `data` is not a class member, so different rules apply.

Comment: @HelloWorld initialization is one of the most complicated topics in C++. I think it could fill a whole book to explain all of it in a way mortals can understand it all (and I am not joking)

Comment: @HelloWorld This is C++. Better programming through oblique syntax complexity. Hehe

Comment: @HelloWorld If I am to give a guess, the reason is simply to make the syntax less ambiguous, as using round parentheses looks like you are declaring a function, which is something people normally do alongside class members, so it could take the parser an arbitrary number of steps to decide whether the code is a member initialization or a function declaration. This kind of initialization is allowed for variables since the syntax is older than curly parentheses initialization, but backwards compatibility prevents it from being removed from the language.

Comment: @IS4 though the same reasoning applies for non class members. `int x(42);` declares an `int`. `int x();` declares a function :/

Comment: @IS4 Really make sense